# Put text as value in input (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, events

I'm trying to put some text inside an input, tried this:

```
$("#someText").click(function () {
var value = $(this).html();
$("input").val(value);
});
```

This is pretty simple, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem is placing your code in a `<script>` tag, but not inside a document-ready function like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#someText").click(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("#someText").click(function () {
      var text = $(this).html();
      $("input").val(text);
    });
</script>
```

or

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#someText").click(function () {
      var text = $(this).html();
       $("input").val(text);
    });

  });
  </script>
```

should work just fine